# Please [notify] the burnination team

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notify) tag seems to me to have no purpose. There is no excerpt, and no wiki. It has 478 questions currently, none of which seem to gain any meaning from having the tag.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?**

Yes - most questions with the tag *do* contain something to do with notifying.

**Is it unambiguous?**

Definitely not; on the first page alone I see questions about:

- Notifying threads in various languages
- Notifications to the user (should be tagged [notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications))
- Functions called `notify`
- notify.js

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Absolutely, as long as it's about something to do with 'notify' in programming.

**Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

It can, but the ambiguity means that other tags should be used instead. If a question is tagged [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notify), that doesn't really tell me anything about it in the tag's current state. The tag only has one follower.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, as per the **Is it unambiguous?** heading above.

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! Please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: `[Notify]` the burnination team!

Comment: So...which conditions does this tag violate? Per your question, it seems to violate only the "is it unambiguous?" condition. But that condition is meant to be applied far more restrictively than you are applying it. If it were to be applied as universally as you are here, we could literally justify burninating *any* tag on the site. Just because you can list multiple possible meanings for a tag does not mean that it is a bad tag. The presence of other tags can serve to functionally disambiguate. I'm not saying [notify] is a good tag, but I'm very tired of "burninate all ambiguous tags".

Comment: So let it be said. So let it be done. Let the fire cleanse.

Comment: @CodyGray In this case, I'd say the tag is very, very ambiguous, to the point of being rather useless. Aside from the lack of any guidance on how the tag _should_ be used, none of the uses it has so far stands out as what should become The One True Usage. All of them would be better served by a more specific tag (and, indeed, most or all of them already are.) Also, Jeff has spoken.

Answer (score -1):

There are some questions regarding Java `wait` and `notify` thread methods with [notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notify) and [wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wait) tags , it should be tagged with [java-threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-threads) or [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading).